# Why SVN assigned mime type application/octate-stream to sql file?

Tags: sql, mime-types, mime

SVN is showing mime type of some SQL files as application/octate-stream. does emailing such files create such problem?

Comment: In what kind of encoding are these files? (UTF-8?) May be they contain special characters ?

Answer (score 0):

Software sometimes makes mistakes too. Just change `svn:mime-type` property to any other you like.